# Accessing a dev server when doing remote / cloud development

Tags: amazon-web-services, localhost, cloud, gatsby, remote-access

I'm attempting to find a completely remote / cloud-based development workflow.

I've created an aws free-tier ec2 instance and on that box I've been developing a gatsby site (the framework doesn't matter, the solution I'm looking for should be framework agnostic).  Since the code is on another box, I can't run the dev server and then from the local computer hit `localhost` as I would normally.

So,

- What do I need to do so that I can run `gatsby develop` and hit my dev server that's hosted on the ec2 box?
- How do I provide public access to that endpoint?
- Is it possible to provide temporary access so that when I log off of the box, it's no longer accessible?
- Is there some mechanism I can put into place so that I'm the only one that can hit that endpoint?
- Are there other features that I should be taking advantage to secure that endpoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't run the dev server and then from the local computer hit localhost as I would normally

You can. You can use `ssh`  to tunnel your remote port to your `localhost`, and access the server from your `localhost`.

> What do I need to do so that I can run gatsby develop and hit my dev server that's hosted on the ec2 box?

ssh into the dev server, run `gatsby develop` and either access it on localhost through ssh tunnel or make it public to access through its public IP address.

Use `sshfs` to mount a development folder on the dev server onto your localhost.

Alternatively, you can setup `vncserver` on the dev server, tunnel vnc connection using ssh, and access the dev server using through a remove desktop. Something liteweight would be good, e.g. `fluxbox` as a desktop environment for vnc.

> Is it possible to provide temporary access so that when I log off of the box, it's no longer accessible?

yes. through ssh tunnel. You close tunnel and the access is finished.

> Is there some mechanism I can put into place so that I'm the only one that can hit that endpoint?

ssh tunnel along with `security group` to allow ssh for your IP address only.

> Are there other features that I should be taking advantage to secure that endpoint?

`Security groups` and `ssh` tunneling would be primary choices to ensure secure access to the dev server.

You can also make the endpoint public, but set security group of your dev server to allow internet access only from your IP.

You could also put the dev server in a private subnet for full separation from the internet. Use bastion host to access it or setup double ssh tunnel to your `localhost`.

Other way is to do all development on `localhost`, push code to `CodeCommit` and have `CodePipeline` manage deployment of your code to your dev server using `CodeDeploy`.

You can also partially eliminate `ssh` by using `SSM Session Manager`.

Hope this helps.